# How to compare two item set lists and count the subset occurence?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a `List<Set<String>> a` that contains:

```
[A,B,C,D,E,F]
[A,B,C,D,E]
[A,B,C,D]
[A,B,C]
```

And then a `List<Set<String>> b` that contains:

```
[A,B]
[A,C]
[A,D]
[B,D]
[B,E]
[B,F]
[C,E]
```

How do I compare each `List<Set<String> a` sets to `List<Set<String> b` sets and then if a set in `b` is a subset of a set in `a`, count it? The output would be something like:

```
[A,B]=4
[A,C]=4
[A,D]=3
[B,D]=3
[B,E]=2
[B,F]=1
[C,E]=2
```

What is a good way for me to implement this by using a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there no shortcut... Just loop through it:

```
for(int i = 0;i<b.size();i++) {
            int cnt = 0;
            for(int j = 0;j<a.size();j++) {
                if(a.get(j).containsAll(b.get(i))) {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(b.get(i) + " = " + cnt);
        }
```

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too, but is there a way to use a map to count instead?

Comment: @Mint How to use a map? What do you want to use the map for(Like want is the key and what is the value)? QAQ

Comment: I think the key would be the set, and the value would be the count? Yesterday I asked sort of a similar question to this (less complicated) but couldn't implement it into this yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64851079/how-to-count-item-occurences-in-a-list-with-sets